# How do I keep the html raw for anchor tags when using jQuerys .html function?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a file that I'm parsing to JSON. I then take that file convert it to html and then display it in a modal. Everything is fine except it takes my anchor tags and displays them as the text encapsulated in the anchor and then makes the link live. I just want it to keep the raw html. Ex. `<a id="foo" href="google.com">bar<a/>` and not just a live link inside the JSON file that says "bar". I tried to using `.text()` as opposed to `.html()` but then its unreadable.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $.toJSON(param),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "SomePage.aspx/someMethod",
    success: function (data) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(data.d);

            //put the json file in modal window
            $('#jsonViewTitle').text("H2 Title inside of modal);
            $('#jsonViewBody').html(myObj._jsonfile);
        }
    },
});
```

EXAMPLE when using .html() - Please note the JSON file is much much longer then this but this should give you an idea. You can click on "bar" and it would take you to google.com

```
      "META": {
        "NAME": "Donald Trump",
        "CREATED": "2017-06-12",
        "UPDATED": "2017-06-12",
        "LANGUAGE": "en",
        "This name changes" "bar"
    },
```

EXAMPLE using .text()

```
    "META": {"NAME": "Donald Trump","CREATED": "2017-06-12","UPDATED": "2017-06-12","LANGUAGE": "en","This name changes" : "<a id="foo" href="google.com">bar</a>"},
```

Comment: Which is it? Either you want the tags to be escaped or you don't. Your question implies you want *neither*.

Comment: could you post some example output of `console.log(data.d)`

Comment: What do you want to display. Raw text or html?

Comment: I don't want them to be. Someone edited my question to make it confusing. I had to then re edit. I want the html <a href="google.com">click</a> and not just 'click' as a live link inside the json file. The link should not be live. Just raw html as text

Comment: But you said using `.text()` made it unreadable? Unless there's something else going on, that is exactly the output I would expect.

Comment: Is it not possible to output it in a readable JSON format but not have the links live and clickable?

Comment: @johnSmith No I can't. It's simple JSON but ONLY the anchor text is showing and I want the entire html to show including the anchor text.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking. `text()` looks like the answer but you explicitly say that has problems… but you've only described that problem is very vague terms. You need to provide a real [mcve]. The Ajax is irrelevant. The value of `myObj.jsonfile` is not.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that you have HTML data and you want that data to be parsed as HTML except for the `<a>` elements, which you want to show the HTML source code of. (In which case: You should structure your data better in the first place)

Comment: @user3225968 See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnsL5pg0/). What are you expecting that's different?

Comment: @Quentin I am getting the JSON from the DB and I cannot change it. I'm displaying it in a modal so the user can read it. But they then copy it and then paste it into a 3rd party application. When I convert it .text then theres not spacing, indentation, ect.  The JSON file is irrelevant. Its perfectly formatted but using .html will turn the anchor tags into clickable links. I just want the code to show and not the anchor text.

Comment: The JSON is not irrelevant. Seeing the data you are trying to format will help us understand the problems you are having with formatting it.

Comment: Oh, if you're looking to preserve whitespace, either surround it in a `<pre>` tag, or use the CSS rule `white-space: pre`.

Comment: "I just want the code to show and not the anchor text." — That's what `text()` does, but you said that was "unreadable". How is it unreadable? Show us a [mcve].

Comment: @Phylogenesis I had the <pre><code></pre></code> but that doesnt work when you use .text()

Comment: `<pre><code></pre></code>` should be `<pre><code></code></pre>` or `<code><pre></pre></code>`. You shouldn't do both anyway...

Comment: Try `$('#jsonViewBody').html('<pre>'); $('#jsonViewBody pre').text(myObj._jsonfile);`.

Comment: @Quentin I added a small tidbit to the question

Comment: I don't see how using `text` instead of `html` could give that result. Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin I wish that wasn't the result but it is and that's my dilemma.

Comment: @user3225968 — Moaning about it won't help. Show us a [mcve] so we can figure out why.

Comment: I was able to figure out a way of doing it with by using a JS replace function amalgamated with global regex search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will search the entire JSON file for the angle bracket i.e. `<` and then replace it with `&lt` which is the less than sign. I added //g which performs a global match by way of regex in the event that there are multiple anchor tags

```
$('#jsonViewBody').html('<pre><code> ' + myObj._jsonfile.replace(/</g, '&lt;') + '</code></pre>');
```

Comment: @GertArnold. I added an explanation to the comments above and the answer.

Answer (score -1):

a script tag may help

```
<script style="display: block">
    <a id="foo" href="google.com">bar<a/>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add specific tags inside your modal to accept the code you want inserted...

```js
var text = "This is a test sentence";

var foo = "<a href='#'>Test link</a>";

var lorem = "lorem ipsum";

$('#modal #first').text(text);
$('#modal #second').text(foo);
//$('#modal #second').html(foo);
$('#modal #third').text(lorem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal">
 <span id="first"></span>
 <span id="second"> </span>
 <span id="third"> </span>
</div>
```

You can uncomment the third line of the JS to `html()` The choice is yours.

**Remember that if you use `.text()` or `.html()` they will overwrite anything inside the targetted div e.g. your modal**

Comment: Explain the downvote? you want to insert an anchor tag inside your modal as a raw piece of text rather than a clickable link. This is an example of just that...